# Como sacar los 3 ultimos solo DJANGO

Tags: django

Hola mi intencion es solo sacar los 3 ultimos que no me salgan todos en un bucle, como debería hacerlo?
Gracias

Codigo

```
html
     <b>Maquina</b>
            {% for q in qs2 %}
            <select>
                <option>{{ q.1 }}</option>
            </select>
            {% endfor %}
views.py
def gestion_ordenes(request):
qs2 = cursor.fetchall()
  context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'qs2': qs2
  }

  return render(request, 'app/gestion_ordenes.html', context)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que le pasas los N elementos al hacer `qs2 = cursor.fetchall()`, porque no le pasas en qs2 únicamente lo que quieres mostrar? (en tu caso los 3 últimos)

Comment: Como le pasarias los 3 ultimos recibidos?

Comment: filtrando antes de hacer el fetchall() con el execute de la otra respuesta y una consulta algo parecida a esta SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date DESC LIMIT 3